# Exercise on arbitrage-free process

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-processes, no-arbitrage-theory

Consider the following problem, from Bjork's *Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time*:

> Consider the standard Black-Scholes model. Derive the arbitrage free price process for the $T$-claim $\mathcal{X}$ where $\mathcal{X}$ is given by $\mathcal{X}=\{S(T)\}^\beta$. Here $\beta$ is a known constant.

My approach.

Let $F(t,s)$ be the price of the claim $\mathcal{X}$ at time $t$, when the underlying spot price is $s$.

The Black-Scholes equation for $F$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
F_t + rsF_s + \frac12 \sigma^2s^2 F_{ss} - rF &= 0 \\
F(T, S(T)) &= S(T)^\beta.
\end{align}
$$

It is convenient to make a change of variables of the form $\tilde{F}(t,s) = e^{-rt}F(t,s)$, so that the associated stochastic process is:
$$
\begin{align}
dX &= rX dt + \sigma X dW \\
X(t) &= s.
\end{align}
$$

After changing variable to $Y = \log X$ and integrating, I find
$$
X(T) = s \exp\left((r-\frac12 \sigma^2)(T-t) + \sigma(W(T) - W(t))\right).
$$
So by the Feynman-Kac formula I have:
$$
\begin{align}
F(t,s) &= e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}\left[X(T)^\beta\right] \\
&= e^{-r(T-t)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s^\beta e^{\beta z} \exp\left(-\frac12 \frac{(z - (r-\frac12\sigma^2)(T-t))^2}{\sigma^2(T-t)}\right)  dz,
\end{align}
$$
which after some computation gives, if I did not make any mistake:
$$
F(t,s)=e^{-r(T-t)}s^\beta \exp\left(\frac12\sigma^2\beta^2(T-t) + (r-\frac12\sigma^2)\beta(T-t)\right).
$$

Does it sound right?

Also, regardless of whether the pricing formula is correct, I am not sure if what I found is really the arbitrage free stochastic process for $\mathcal{X}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a lognormally distributed variable, $X = e^{\mu + \nu Z}$, so $\ln X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\nu^2$, and $Z$ is normally distributed, then
$$
E\left[ X^n \right] = e^{n\mu + \frac{1}{2} n^2\nu^2}
$$
This solves your question with $X = S_T/S_t$, $n = \beta$, $\mu = (r -\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2) (T-t)$ and $\nu = \sigma \sqrt{T-t}$ in the Black Scholes world.

See also the following wiki page for other properties of lognormal distribution:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: Ok, so using the expression for $E[X^n]$ as you suggest, and plugging in $X=S_T/s$, given that $s$ is deterministic I would have: 
$$
F(t,s) = e^{-r(T-t)} s^\beta E[X^\beta],
$$
which gives precisely the formula I found (I consider the discounted value at time $t$ of the risk-neutral expectation).

Comment: @J.D. yes, that's correct. It's good/useful that you derived it yourself.